# Handling lack of acknowledgement socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I built a small chat in node.js using the https://socket.io library.

One of the functions in my chat is that when you click on a user, you can see if they have you added and if they're online. (they could be in another room)

Here's a snippet of code from the server:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('added friend check', userid, function(ftype) {
    online = true;
    socket.emit('mutual friend answer', id, online, ftype);
});
```

(using the method in http://socket.io/docs/ on sending and getting data (acknowledgements))

My question is, let's say the user to whom I sent "added friend check" doesn't respond to the request, how do I detect that and act upon it?

Obviously their network could be slow so you have to give them some sort of time to respond. So let's say you give it 2 seconds.

e.g. in this case I may just send back a response to the client who clicked on that person and say the user can't be reached and their internet connection might be weak

Comment: Shouldn't this work a bit different way? I mean when a user connects you check what friends he/she has and get all needed info for each user(if they have you added and if they're online) and send this back to the user. And that's it.

Comment: I mean I could do that, but I'd have to store it all in an object. That could add up fast depending on how many friends they have and how many people are connected. I'm really not too sure that that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Well if you expect more then a few thousands of users then you gonna need database(redis maybe) but for hundreds or couple thousands the *object* is just fine i think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into redis. I don't know how many users I'll have, but I want to future proof it in case it grows to be that large. It seems more than doable using that. I appreciate your help.